# Vue 3 composition API object data not updating after apply the filter

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have one reactive object of the product list, I am showing the products in my template. Now I made one filter which filters the product object by
the product type key of the object. The issue is when I applied the filter it shows values proper in the console but in the template, it doesn't reflect any changes. In vue 2 I used `this.$forceUpdate();` and it seems to work for me. What is the correct way to do this thing in vue3 composition API?

I am doing something wrong but didn't get the exact idea of what to do for this. Thank you in advacne.

Here I attached my code sandbox link
[Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-snowflake-bgmbph?file=/src/App.vue)

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <div
      class="assets-dropdwon accordian"
      v-for="(pata, index) in productData"
      :key="index"
    >
      {{ pata["name"] }}
    </div>

    <button @click="filterProductData()">FILTER</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { reactive } from "vue";
export default {
  name: "App",
  setup() {
    const productTypeVal = 1;
    let productData = reactive({
      1: {
        sort: 1,
        name: "Product 1",
        product_type: 1,
      },
      2: {
        sort: -1,
        name: "Product 2",
        product_type: 2,
      },
      3: {
        sort: 0,
        name: "Product 3",
        product_type: 1,
      },
      4: {
        sort: 5,
        name: "Product 4",
        product_type: 3,
      },
    });
    let productInitData = {
      1: {
        sort: 1,
        name: "Product 1",
        product_type: 1,
      },
      2: {
        sort: -1,
        name: "Product 2",
        product_type: 2,
      },
      3: {
        sort: 0,
        name: "Product 3",
        product_type: 1,
      },
      4: {
        sort: 5,
        name: "Product 4",
        product_type: 3,
      },
    };

    let filteredProducts = reactive({});

    const filterProductData = () => {
      Object.keys(productInitData).map((key) => {
        if (productInitData[key]["product_type"] === productTypeVal) {
          filteredProducts[key] = productInitData[key];
        }
      });
      productData = filteredProducts;
      console.log(productData);
    };

    return {
      productData,
      productTypeVal,
      filterProductData,
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at the [Vue.js Documentation: Limitations of `reactive()`](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#limitations-of-reactive):

> The reactive() API has two limitations:
>
> 1. It only works for object types (objects, arrays, and collection types such as Map and Set). It cannot hold primitive types such as string, number or boolean.
> 2. Since Vue's reactivity tracking works over property access, we must always keep the same reference to the reactive object. This means we can't easily "replace" a reactive object because the reactivity connection to the first reference is lost.

The latter point is the issue with your code: you're not changing the state of this object's properties, which is allowed, but rather changing the reference that the variable refers to and I think that this reassignment of reference is what is causing the loss of reactivity.

So there are several possible solutions that I see you can use, including:

1. Changing the actual object properties of `productData`. To do this, you probably will want to remove all the properties and re-add them from `productInitData` if they meet criteria:

```js
function myFilter() {
  // remove all properties from productData
  Object.keys(productData).forEach((key) => delete productData[key]);

  // re-add properties that we want to display
  Object.keys(productInitData).forEach((key) => {
    if (productInitData[key]["product_type"] === productTypeVal) {
      productData[key] = productInitData[key];
    }
  });
}
```

2. Using and displaying a computed property where the v-for is on the `computedProducts` field. This may require other fields, and in my example, I use a boolean field, `isFiltered`:

```js
let isFiltered = reactive({ value: false });

function toggleFiltered() {
  isFiltered.value = !isFiltered.value;
}

const computedProducts = computed(() => {
  if (isFiltered.value) {
    let myFilteredProducts = {};
    Object.keys(productInitData).map((key) => {
      if (productInitData[key]["product_type"] === productTypeVal) {
        myFilteredProducts[key] = productInitData[key];
      }
    });
    return myFilteredProducts;
  } else {
    return productInitData;
  }
});
```

and in the template:

```html
<div
  class="assets-dropdwon accordian"
  v-for="(pata, index) in computedProducts"
  :key="index"
>
  {{ pata["name"] }}
</div>

<button @click="toggleFiltered()">FILTER 1</button>
```

3. Wrapping your reactive object in another object so that the inner object's reference can be changed and it remains reactive. But if we're going this far, might as well use a store such as Pinia or Vuex.

---

For example:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <div
      class="assets-dropdwon accordian"
      v-for="(pata, index) in computedProducts"
      :key="index"
    >
      {{ pata["name"] }}
    </div>

    <button @click="toggleFiltered()">FILTER 1</button>

    <br />
    <br />
    <div
      class="assets-dropdwon accordian"
      v-for="(pata, index) in productData"
      :key="index"
    >
      {{ pata["name"] }}
    </div>

    <button @click="myFilter">FILTER 2</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { computed, reactive } from "vue";
export default {
  name: "App",
  setup() {
    const productTypeVal = 1;
    let productData = reactive({
      1: {
        sort: 1,
        name: "Product 1",
        product_type: 1,
      },
      2: {
        sort: -1,
        name: "Product 2",
        product_type: 2,
      },
      3: {
        sort: 0,
        name: "Product 3",
        product_type: 1,
      },
      4: {
        sort: 5,
        name: "Product 4",
        product_type: 3,
      },
    });
    let productInitData = {
      1: {
        sort: 1,
        name: "Product 1",
        product_type: 1,
      },
      2: {
        sort: -1,
        name: "Product 2",
        product_type: 2,
      },
      3: {
        sort: 0,
        name: "Product 3",
        product_type: 1,
      },
      4: {
        sort: 5,
        name: "Product 4",
        product_type: 3,
      },
    };

    let isFiltered = reactive({ value: false });

    function toggleFiltered() {
      isFiltered.value = !isFiltered.value;
    }

    const computedProducts = computed(() => {
      if (isFiltered.value) {
        let myFilteredProducts = {};
        Object.keys(productInitData).map((key) => {
          if (productInitData[key]["product_type"] === productTypeVal) {
            myFilteredProducts[key] = productInitData[key];
          }
        });
        return myFilteredProducts;
      } else {
        return productInitData;
      }
    });

    function myFilter() {
      // remove all properties from productData
      Object.keys(productData).forEach((key) => delete productData[key]);

      // re-add properties that we want to display
      Object.keys(productInitData).forEach((key) => {
        if (productInitData[key]["product_type"] === productTypeVal) {
          productData[key] = productInitData[key];
        }
      });
    }

    return {
      productData,
      productTypeVal,
      computedProducts,
      toggleFiltered,
      myFilter,
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```